# Bug in 'messages' Webhook Event on Instagram Meta App Dashboard - Looking for Solutions

Tags: facebook, bots, backend, instagram, webhooks

I suspect there might be a bug in play here.

On the Meta App dashboard, within the Instagram webhooks section, there are various webhook events available for testing: comments, live_comments, mentions, message_reactions, messages, messaging_handover, messaging_postbacks, messaging_referral, messaging_seen, standby, and story_insights. All of these webhook events, along with their corresponding webhook endpoints, can be successfully received and tested. However, the "messages" event has never been received successfully.

To replicate this, I've provided a straightforward sample code:

GitHub Repository:https://github.com/WantenMN/instagram-webhook

You don't need an Instagram account, a Business account, a Facebook page, nor do you need to acquire a user access token or page access token. All you need is a Facebook developer account; having only this is sufficient to replicate this bug.

Reproduction steps:

1. Clone the code to your local environment, install the dependencies, and run it using the command "npm run start" or "pnpm start". Utilize ngrok by executing "ngrok http 3000".
2. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/ and log in or register.
3. Navigate to the My Apps page and create a new App, selecting either Business or Consumer as the App type.
4. Set up the webhook by choosing Instagram, then edit the subscription. Fill in the Callback URL with the Forwarding URL generated by ngrok, followed by "/webhook". You can use "abc" as the Verify token.
5. Below, click the Test button to test any Webhook event. Observe the code output window; the bug will be replicated. All tested webhook events can be received, except for the "messages" event.

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. Thank you!